# PostgreSql - SELECT Max repeated from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider i have two table `tab1` and `tab2` :

```
+-----------+-----------+
| ID_t1     |  col2     |
+-----------+-----------+
| 1         |  1        |
+-----------+-----------+
| 2         |  1        |
+-----------+-----------+
```

And **tab2**:

```
+-----------+-----------+
| ID_t2     |  ID_t1    |
+-----------+-----------+
| 1         |  1        |
+-----------+-----------+
| 2         |  1        |
+-----------+-----------+
| 3         |  1        |
+-----------+-----------+
| 4         |  2        |
+-----------+-----------+
```

I try to find the object that have the `tab1.col1 = 1` and the maximum line in the table tab2 so the result should be like the object 1

```
+-----------+-----------+
| ID_t1     |  col2     |
+-----------+-----------+
| 1         |  1        |
+-----------+-----------+
```

I try this :

```
SELECT ID_t1 FROM tab1 
     WHERE tab1.col2 = 1 and 
           ID_t1 = (SELECT ID_t1 FROM tab2 WHERE -- MAX ONE REPEATED IN THIS TABLE)
```

I really stack how can i compete this query, can you help me please.

Comment: Are you using MySQL, Oracle or Postgresql? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: i'm using Postgresql @jarlh

Comment: What is the "maximum line in the table `tab2`"?  I see no column called `line`.  SQL Tables represent *unordered* sets; there is no maximum of something unless an ordering is specified.

Comment: Please clarify. Use consistent column names. Provide a second example.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i mean the number of repeated line, for example the ID_t1 =1 is repeated 3 times and

Comment: So for col2 = 2 we'd get an empty result set, because col2 = 2 links to ID_t1 = 2 which is not the most often occurring ID_t1 in tab2. Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer for my question :

```
SELECT 
  tab1 as id, 
  COUNT(*) as nombre
FROM 
  tab1, tab2 
WHERE 
  tab2.ID_t1 = tab1.ID_t1 and
  tab1.col2 = 1
GROUP BY tab2.ID_t1
ORDER BY nombre desc LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this:

```
SELECT ID_t1 
FROM tab1 
WHERE tab1.col2 = 1 AND
      ID_t1 = (SELECT ID_t1 
               FROM tab2 
               GROUP BY ID_t1 
               ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
               LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: @YCF_L Have you included `GROUP BY ID_t1` in your query?

Comment: sorry sorry sorry, its my mistakes

Comment: sorry i think i makes a mistakes, both of the ID_t1 = 1 and 2 should have the same col2

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `LIMIT` in subquery:

```
select
from tabl1
where id_t1 in (
    select id_t1
    from tab2
    group by id_t1
    order by count(*) desc
    limit 1
) and col2 = 1;
```

Comment: sorry i think i makes a mistakes, both of the ID_t1 = 1 and 2 should have the same col2

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 select ID_t1, col2 from tab1 
 where ID_t1=1 and 
 col2=
 (
 select ID_t1 from tab2 
 group by ID_t1
 order by count(*) DESC
 limit 1
 )
```

Comment: sorry i think i makes a mistakes, both of the ID_t1 = 1 and 2 should have the same col2